# Get the voyage name using dax

Tags: dax, ssas, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to use Dax in Powerbi to get the last voyage of a customer.
I have 3 tables
Client

```
id_client id_voyage id_date
1 5 20170109
1 1 20190312
1 3 20221225
2 1 20220114
2 1 20220125
2 4 20221214
```

Voyage

```
id_voyage voyage_name
1 Paris
2 London
3 Madrid
4 NYC
5 LA
```

Date(all date from 2010 01 01 to 2050 12 31)

```
id_date Date
20100101 2010/01/01
...
20501231 2050/12/31
```

What I need it is the last voyage :
id_client date voyage_name
1 2022/12/25 Madrid
2 2022/12/14 NYC

I tried just to get the last date with the code below

```
MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Date'[Date]))
```

but it did not work

When I added the measure in a table that contains only id_client,date it added all the date in the measure

```
id_client date voyage_name
1 2010/01/01
1 2010/01/02
1 2010/01/03
...
1 2050/12/30
1 2050/12/31
```

If someone can help or at least explain why it multiply the lines

The model is simple

```
Date 1-->* Client *<--1 Voyage
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need something like SUMMARIZE or SUMMARIZECOLUMNS for that? (You GROUP your records by Client and return MAX(VoyageDate))
you can do it either in DAX or in Powerquery, but PowerQuery will remove non-max values.

Comment: What relationships do you have between your tables?

Comment: date is linked to client (one-many), voyage is linked to client (one-many)
I tried with summarizecolumns but the output is empty 
var MaxDate = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Client[id_client],"max",MAX(Date[Date]))
return
SELECTEDVALUE(Voyage'[voyage_name])

Comment: Please mark your old questions as solved and provide a picture of your data model.

Comment: Model added, I m not able to close them